# Woocommerce add to cart message not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After implementing and doing design changes locally on a project, the woocommerce messages are not showing anymore on the single product page. I don't get any `console errors`, so I don't think it has anything to do with that.  And the request is processed since when I go to see the cart from another page, then the item that I was trying to add is on the list, it is just that the message doesn't show on a singe product page. I am not sure where to go about?

This is the `add-to-cart/variable` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.4.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="variations" cellspacing="0">
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-3 columns">
                            <label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>" class="text-left middle">
                                <strong><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></strong>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="small-9 columns">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
      <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <div class="row single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">
      <div class="small-9 small-offset-3 columns">
            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_single_variation Hook
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * woocommerce_single_variation hook. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_single_variation Hook
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
      </div>
        </div>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like quite an old version of the `variable.php` template, if you have anything higher than **WooCommerce 2.4.0** installed (i checked against the **2.5.0** version of this template) there are enough significant changes that might break certain parts of WooCommerce.

One difference that immediately stood out to me was that the `data-product_variations` attribute on the form in later versions uses `htmlspecialchars` instead of `esc_attr`.

Hope this helps!